# How to fetch values from database/custom fields for calculating price in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I've added custom fields from backend to `Admin > Config > Sales`. Now, I want to get their values and the details of the product added by the owner for calculating product price before displaying on product page.

[image: Custom fields - price]

Apart from this I need to check which type of gold/silver/diamond is selected. So the eqation will be 
'`Value from database which was selected`' * '`Quantity`' + '`Making Charges`' = '`Final Price`'

If its in PHP I can do it. But I don't know how can I do it in #Magento? Please guide me if any one can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can access config value by using following way:

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

sectionName, groupName and fieldName are present in etc/system.xml file of your module.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I suppose to fix this code? And how can I get the output?

Comment: you can write anyware in magento in controller,block,phtml to get its value.

Comment: Could you please suggest me a link from where I can learn Magento coding and file structure.

Comment: You can refer below link will help you to understand and learn magento.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/